# htmlentities works when i run it within an echo but not when i define it in a var

Tags: php

I am making a contact form to be sent off via email however i cant get htmlentities to work correctly with my form. I have echo'd it to see if its working.

How i want it to work : lets say i put in <"">

```
 $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
 $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
 echo $name;
```

It should output &lt&quot&quot&gt but it outputs <"">.

When i run the htmlentities in an echo it seems to work.

```
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
echo htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

This then outputs it correctly. Why is this and how do i get it working the first way?

Comment: When you see it output `<"">` are you viewing that as html or text? The difference is that if it is html, `<"">` is the correct output because the entities are parsed into their characters for display. If it wasn't working, you would see nothing in html because that would look like a tag, even if poorly formed. If you were just echo'ing that out, I would expect to see `<"">` on the screen and if you view source you would see the `&whatever;` entities.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks that makes sence to me now :). Would what i have for the first option protect me against people putting javascript into my form then?

Comment: It depends on what you are using this for but most likely yes. If you see a script tag on screen and it is entities when you view the source then won't run the script.